# Component state reverts back to default before correcting itself very fast

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I have a small issue that I can't figure out why it happens. After signing in, if the user attempts to access the login page, it will redirect to the home page. However, I'm not sure why my /signin page flashes/appears for half a second before the redirect happens.

I'll try my best to explain the flow of the code:

Whenever a user logins, state.signIn.signInSuccess is set to true. This state is mapped to a prop in my routes component, where I pass it down as a prop to my AuthorizedRoutes component. The authorizedRoutes component check if signInSuccess is true or not and will render the /signin page or redirect. When I try to access the signin page I console.log the state, signInSuccess shows up as false for half a second before changing to true even though the user is already signed in. It's a small issue, but I want to understand why the state is changing to false for that half a second.

If anyone could help me, I'd appreciate it. Thanks

```
////signin action creators////
import { firebaseApp } from '../firebase.js';
import { SIGNIN_PENDING, SIGNIN_SUCCESS, SIGNIN_FAIL } from '../constants/signin.js';


const setSignInPending = signInPending => {
    return{
        type:SIGNIN_PENDING,
        signInPending
    };
};

const setSignInSuccess = signInSuccess => {
    return{
        type:SIGNIN_SUCCESS,
        signInSuccess
    };
};

const setSignInFail = signInError => {
    return{
        type:SIGNIN_FAIL,
        signInError
    };      
};

export const signIn = (email, password) => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(setSignInPending(true));
        return firebaseApp.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then(res => {
                dispatch(setSignInPending(false));
                dispatch(setSignInSuccess(true));
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('error', error);
                dispatch(setSignInPending(false));
                dispatch(setSignInFail(error.code));
            })
    }
};

export const signedIn = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(setSignInSuccess(true));
        dispatch(setSignInFail(null));
    };
};



////signin reducer////
import { SIGNIN_PENDING, SIGNIN_SUCCESS, SIGNIN_FAIL } from '../constants/signin.js';

const defaultState = {
    signInPending: false,
    signInSuccess: false,
    signInError: null,
};

const signIn = (state = defaultState, action) => {
    let signInState = null;
    switch (action.type){
        case SIGNIN_PENDING:
            signInState = {
                ...state,
                signInPending: action.signInPending
            };
            return signInState;
        case SIGNIN_SUCCESS:
            signInState = {
                ...state,
                signInSuccess: action.signInSuccess,
            };
            return signInState;
        case SIGNIN_FAIL:
            signInState = {
                ...state,
                signInError: action.signInError
            };
            return signInState;
        default:
            return state;
    };
};

export default signIn;





////Routes component////
class Routes extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            // user ? dispatch(setSignedInTrue()) : dispatch(setSignedInFalse());
            if (user){
                this.props.signedIn();
            }
        });
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/' render={(props) => (<App signInSuccess={this.props.signInSuccess} {...props}/>)} />
                    <AuthorizedRoute signedIn={this.props.signInSuccess} path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
                    <AuthorizedRoute signedIn={this.props.signInSuccess} path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
                    <Route component={InvalidPage} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        );
    }
};

Routes.propTypes = {
    signedIn: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return{
        signInSuccess: state.signIn.signInSuccess
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return{
        signedIn: () => dispatch(signedIn()),
        signOut: () => dispatch(signOut())
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Routes);



////AuthorizedRoutes Component////
class AuthorizedRoute extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    };

    render(){
        console.log(this.props);
        const { component: Component, ...rest } = this.props;
        return(
            <Route {...rest} render={props => {
                if (this.props.signedIn){
                    return <Redirect to="/" />
                } else if (this.props.signedIn === false){
                    return <Component {...props} />
                } else{
                    return null;
                }
            }} />
        );
    }
};

AuthorizedRoute.propTypes = {
    signInSuccess: PropTypes.bool
};

export default AuthorizedRoute;
```

Answer (score 0):

You trigger 2 separate Redux state changes:

```
dispatch(setSignInPending(false));
dispatch(setSignInSuccess(true));
```

those will each cause a re-render, so when you `setSignInPending(false)`, there is a render where `signInPending` is false but `setSignInSuccess(true)` hasn't been called.

This is a common usage of Redux, to use it with simple getters/setters.  Think of it more like events which occur which can mutate multiple aspects of the state.  I think you actually only have 1 event:  signInSuccess (or fail), and you simply need to set pending to false in that reducer case because you know you got a response.  That way there is only 1 Redux state change and when the render is called the state isn't in an invalid state as it is now.

```
////signin reducer////
import { SIGNIN_SUCCESS, SIGNIN_FAIL } from '../constants/signin.js';

const defaultState = {
    signInPending: false,
    signInSuccess: false,
    signInError: null,
};

const signIn = (state = defaultState, action) => {
    let signInState = null;
    switch (action.type){
        case SIGNIN_SUCCESS:
            signInState = {
                ...state,
                signInSuccess: action.signInSuccess,
                signInPending: false,
                signInError: null
            };
            return signInState;
        case SIGNIN_FAIL:
            signInState = {
                ...state,
                signInError: action.signInError,
                signInPending: false,
                signInSuccess: false
            };
            return signInState;
        default:
            return state;
    };
};

export default signIn;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I use pending when I'm waiting for a response so that I display a loading animation. Without the pending, I'm not sure how I would go about it. Also I understand what you're saying, but I'm not sure how that would relate to when I call signedIn() from my action creator: `export const signedIn = () => {
 return dispatch => {
  dispatch(setSignInSuccess(true));
  dispatch(setSignInFail(null));
 };
};` This gets called when a logged in user is returning back to the page. I check that they are logged in already and setSignInSuccess to true, but it flips to false then true

Comment: Inside my signedIn, if there's 2 state changes, one involving setSignInSuccess(true) and the other setSignInFail(null), why would signInSuccess ever revert back to false when I set it to true before the user tries to access the signin page

Comment: I added the signInError: null state change to the reducer.  You would also not dispatch 2 separate actions in your signedIn action:  `export const signedIn = () => { return dispatch => { dispatch(setSignInSuccess(true)); }; };`

Comment: each time you call dispatch a new render happens.  so you can see you end up in cases where one variable has been toggled (pending), but the others have not (signInSuccess, signInError).  You want to minimize the separate dispatch calls and make all the changes at once in your reducer.  Otherwise there are renders that occur in an invalid state.